# UICollectionViewCell Overlay View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a UICollectionViewCell with .xib.

[image]

Here is the Structure of the xib file

[image]

As you can see every element at the same level and 3 image views and a single button. But at run time there is a UIView in front these elements.

[image]

UI structure at runtime.

[image]

**I need to understand why this is happening and what is the solution. Because of this overlay UIView clicks events not pass down to the button.**

Comment: Post the code of your `cellForRow` and cell's `init?(coder:)` functions

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I was using UIView in the XIB that created by default when creating a xib file. Instead of using that I tried with UICollectionViewCell element as the parent and it worked for me.